# Why is this printing first index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

Working on this problem for a python course and can't for the life of me figure out why this doesn't work. I'd rather it give me an error than print 0!

Problem gives me the variable `x` with the string shown and need to print the index of the first time `y` is used.

```
x = 'Poisson geometry plays an important role in noncommutative geometry.'
y = 'u'

i = 0
while i == 0:
    for o in x:
        if o == y:
            print(y, "is first seen in index = ", y.index(o))
            i += 1
```

Code shown returns:

```
u is first seen in index =  0
```

Comment: `y.index(o)` is in the branch where `o == y`. The position of any string in itself is 0.

Comment: Although the main issue is addressed by the answers below, your `while` loop also seems unnecessary.  Note that it will run through the entire `for` loop during the first iteration of the while loop.  Including the while loop as you've written it just causes the program to keep looping forever (even after having searched the whole string) in the case where no match is found.

Comment: And as @T4roy points out, you don't need the `for` loop either if you're already using `.index` to find the character you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want index in `x`? In that case, use `x.index(o)` where searches for `o` in `x`.

```
x = 'Poisson geometry plays an important role in noncommutative geometry.'
y = 'u'

i = 0
while i == 0:
    for o in x:
        if o == y:
            print(y, "is first seen in index = ", x.index(o))
            i += 1
```

However, the correct way to write it is without the loop:

```
x = 'Poisson geometry plays an important role in noncommutative geometry.'
y = 'u'

print(y, "is first seen in index = ", x.index(y))
```

output:

```
u is first seen in index =  51
```

Comment: Yes I see now you don't need the loop but it was in the "While" learning section so I went right there not thinking about the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially having it look for `'u'.index('u')`

`y.index(o)` should be `x.index(o)` for this example.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to iterate? If you keep your first 2 lines then use`x.index(y)` you will get the same result without using a `while`, `for` or `if`.

```
x = 'Poisson geometry plays an important role in noncommutative geometry.'
y = 'u'
print(y, "is first seen in index = ", x.index(y))
```

Comment: It seems like you don't need to iterate. The problem is in the "While" learning section so my brain went right there.